# How can I retrieve the current product id from database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get product id, so I can save to `order_product` table. But I'm stuck.

Here is my store function in checkout Controller

```
//Insert into order product table
if ($order) {
    foreach(session('cart')  as $item) {
        if (empty($item)) {
            continue;
        }

        OrderProduct::create([
            'order_id' => $order->id ?? null,
            'product_id' =>DB::table('products')->get('id'),
           // $products=DB::table('products')->where('id',$id)->get();
            'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
        ]);
   }
}




CartController

   public function cart()
{
    return view('cart');
}

public function addToCart($id)
{
    $userId = Auth::id();
    $products = Products_model::find($id);
    if(!$products) {

        abort(404);

    }

    $cart = session()->get('cart');

    // if cart is empty then this the first product
    if(!$cart) {

        $cart = [
                $id => [
                    "pro_name" => $products->pro_name,
                    "quantity" => 1,
                    "pro_price" => $products->pro_price,
                    "image" => $products->image
                ]
        ];

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }

    // if cart not empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity
    if(isset($cart[$id])) {

        $cart[$id]['quantity']++;

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');

    }

    // if item not exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
    $cart[$id] = [
        "pro_name" => $products->pro_name,
        "quantity" => 1,
        "pro_price" => $products->pro_price,
        "image" => $products->image
    ];

    session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    if($request->id and $request->quantity)
    {
        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        $cart[$request->id]["quantity"] = $request->quantity;

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        session()->flash('success', 'Cart updated successfully');
    }
  }

public function remove(Request $request)
{
    if($request->id) {

        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        if(isset($cart[$request->id])) {

            unset($cart[$request->id]);

            session()->put('cart', $cart);
        }

        session()->flash('success', 'Product removed successfully');
    }
}

}
```

I need to be able to save current `product_id` associated with the order in the database. Because right now it shows

```
Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":1},{"id":2}]' for column 'product_id'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You get that value since you're fetching _all_ `id`'s from the `products` table. You need to have a `where` in there so you fetch the correct product. Why don't you simply store the product id in your cart together with the quantity? How do you currently even know what quantity belongs to which product in your cart?

Comment: are you want to save multiple products for single order?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson right now the quantity is fetching correctly. After asking this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571332/laravel-get-property-of-non-object?noredirect=1#comment99722231_56571332 now the problem is product id

Comment: To quote the questions from my previous comment that you didn't answer: _"Why don't you simply store the product id in your cart together with the quantity? How do you currently even know what quantity belongs to which product in your cart?"_. We can't possibly know how to get the correct `id` if we have no clue what your variables contains. What you should do is to store the quantity and product id together when you add a product to the cart. Then you would already have the id in the above code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i updated the question and added cart controller How do i save the product id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually already saving the product id as the array index:

```
$cart = [
    $id => [ // $id is the product id
        // ...
    ]
];
```

So if you want to get that id in your foreach loop, use the format:

```
foreach ($array as $index => $value)
```

Your code would then be:

```
foreach (session('cart') as $productId => $item) {
    if (empty($item)) {
        continue;
    }

    OrderProduct::create([
        'order_id'   => $order->id ?? null,
        'product_id' => $productId,
        'quantity'   => $item['quantity'],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each item in your cart array is indexed by a product ID, you can get the index within the `foreach` loop.

```
 if ($order) {
    foreach(session('cart')  as $productId => $item) {
        if (empty($item)) {
            continue;
        }

        OrderProduct::create([
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'product_id' =>$productId,
            'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
        ]);
   }
}
```

You also likely don't need the null coalescing operator since you're already checking if `$order` is a truthy value at the beginning.

Comment: _"In that case, you can simply get the ID from the item directly."_ - How do you know that? We have _zero_ clue what the variable `$item` contains or how the cart is populated.

Comment: i get an error undefined index:id, the question has more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571332/laravel-get-property-of-non-object?noredirect=1#comment99722231_56571332

Comment: @joh - Please don't refer to another question to give us context. Edit your question to contain all needed information instead. Write it as if the other question doesn't exist.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I assumed it contained the Product object, based on what the OP had earlier stated.

Comment: @joh COuld you please let us know what ```cart``` contains?

Comment: Except from the fact that `quantity` isn't a product property. It's a cart and order property.